# View Pager with all visible pages behind current opened page

Tags: java, android, view, android-viewpager

Hello guys I have to create custom animations between pages in *viewpager*
[image]

1. The way it should function is that all 4 pages have to be visible (or in background).
2. Secondly moving between pages would be possible by scrolling upwards/downwards.
3. At last moving to specific page would be possible by click on the black button (part of visible page)

I hope that image ilustrate functionality clearly.

I was looking for solution, but haven't found some.
The best answer I've found use minus margin in order to show adjacent pages - but they never hide behind current page. 
I have tried to found solution at [Libraries for Developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos) , but also with failure.

I would be very thankfull for any advice!

Comment: You can try this https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck.

Comment: @murt I hope, [This](https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView) might give you some idea

Comment: Finnally I've achieved it using BottomSheets, not perfectly but it's enough